# Error when moving files

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a code that moves files in my download folder to other specified folders but I keep getting errors. Here's my code.

```
import os
import shutil
series = []
for i in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\Mike\\Downloads\\Video'):
    if ('.mp4') in i:
        series.append(i)

for j in series:
    if 'Thrones' in j:
        shutil.move(j,'C:\\Users\\Mike\\Desktop\\')
```

I keep getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Mike/Downloads/Video/Arrange.py", line 70, in <module>
Series(series)
File "C:/Users/Mike/Downloads/Video/Arrange.py", line 48, in Series
shutil.move(serie, 'C:\\Users\\Mike\\Desktop\\Movies\\Series\\Lost\\s2\\')
File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\shutil.py", line 536, in move
raise Error("Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst)
shutil.Error: Destination path 'C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\Movies\Series\Lost\s2\lost - s02e08 (o2tvseries.com).mp4' already exists
>>>
```

but the file actually moves. How do I move the files without getting this error each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get is Windows platform specific. You are using `shutil.move` which uses `os.rename` under the hood. From [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename):

> On Windows, if dst already exists, OSError will be raised even if it is a file

You could check if the file exists in the destination before you move it and depending what you want to achieve:

1) don't overwrite the destination, just remove file from source
2) remove the file from source first and overwrite the destination

Below you can find implementation of solution 2)

```
import os

for name in series:
    if 'Thrones' in name:
        if not os.path.isfile(name):
            shutil.move(name, 'C:\\Users\\Mike\\Desktop\\')
        else:
            os.remove(name)
```